# HQL JAVA - How to make combinaison condition with multiple list

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have an unusual problem in HQL and I havn't found the solution ->

I have a table with columns A,B,C,D... and i want to do a request with a list of combinaison of B,C,D . example :

Table

```
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+<br/>
 |----PK----|-----B----|-----C----|-----D----|<br/>
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+<br/>
 |-----1-----|-----2-----|-----3----|-----4----|<br/>
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+<br/>
 |-----2-----|-----5-----|-----4----|-----7----|<br/>
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+<br/>
 |-----3-----|-----7-----|-----9----|-----8----|<br/>
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+<br/>
 |-----4-----|-----6-----|-----4----|-----9----|<br/>
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+<br/>
 |-----5-----|-----6-----|-----4----|-----7----|<br/>
```

I have a list of combinaison of B,C,D like : comb1 : 5,4,7 | comb2 : 6,4,9 .
And i want to retrieve all row which has one of these combine.
In this example i want to retrieve  row 2 and 4.

I tried this approch : creating 3 lists B_List, C_List, D_List and this request:

Select * 
FROM entity e 
WHERE e.B in(:B_List) AND e.c in(:C_List) AND e.d in(:D_List)

But this request may retrieve unwanted rows like row 5.

I tried this too :

SELECT * 
FROM entity e
WHERE (e.b,e.c,e.d) in (:B_List,:C_List,:D_List)

but this syntax seems wrong in HQL.
Someone have an idea? sorry for my english >.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you make your :B_LIST :C_LIST and :D_LIST , but I can suggest you make them as :BCD_LIST (the concatenation of them) and then compare it like this:

```
Select * FROM entity e 
WHERE concat(e.B,',',e.c,',',e.d)  in(:BCD_List)
```

Comment: @Zakaria Just each of the list item as  '5,4,7' with comma separated

Comment: Thank you , that's exactly what I wanted.
I did not know that i could approach like this!

Comment: No problem @Zakaria :)